# Unable to install robot framework for jython

Tags: pip, robotframework, jython

I am trying to install robot framework for jython in C:\jython2.7.0\bin by the command `pip install robotframework`. But it is throwing below error:

> C:\jython2.7.0\bin\pip.exe__main__.py run on Thu Sep 28 14:34:34 2017
>   Downloading/unpacking robotframework
>   Downloading/unpacking
>   robotframework
>   ←[31m  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
>   ←[0m←[31m  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement   robotframework
>   ←[0m Cleaning up...

I am not getting jython interpreter in eclipse due to this.

Comment: When browsing the internet, is there a proxy set in your browser to access the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always download the package from https://pypi.python.org/ (with your browser) an then install from local path, like:

```
jython -m pip install <path to downloaded package>
```

Or, if you are behind a Proxy, you can define:

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://your.proxy.url:port
```

(this works with Python)

Comment: Thank you so much, Helio!  It solved my issue. Now, I have robot framework for Jython is installed in my system. The package I downloaded and installed is 'robotframework-3.0.1rc2.tar.gz'.

Comment: Thanks. You should mark my answer as accepted.

Please note that there is a more recent version of Robot Framework, 3.0.2.